# My UK visa has been refused please help I want to re apply

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds

[image] every month in my bank statement I transferred money to my cousin to save and he transferred it back before my visa....

Comment: @Alexis Ashman Do the entries in your bank statement show the money leaving your account and being transferred back? That pattern makes little sense - why not just save the money in a separate account in your own name? Why did your leave letter show longer time off than your planned visit? There’s no point re-applying unless you can clarify all of the refusal points and provide suitable evidence.

Comment: @Traveller Presumably, the asker wanted to avoid the temptation to spend the money themself.

Answer (score 8):

To summarize:

- You want to spend practically all of your savings on a trip to the UK
- You plan to visit for 55 days and take 90 days off work, long periods of time that raise the question of how you'll support yourself after spending all your money on a trip
- Your bank statements show suspiciously unexplained transactions because you transfer money back and forth between your account and your cousin's

None of this is a recipe to be granted a visa right now. And if you're refused again, you'll start to develop a record of serial refusals that could hurt your case; you don't want to look desperate to get into the UK.

I'd wait to reapply until you have your situation at home more in order. Read [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and aim for stable finances that show a history of salary deposits and greater savings, without unusual transfers (or if you do have necessary transfers, with documentation to show where the money is coming from and why you're receiving it). Have a clear explanation for the amount of time you'll be away, an amount that makes sense in proportion to your economic circumstances. Build up sufficient savings so that you won't be emptying your bank account to afford the trip. At that point, you'll have a greater chance of success.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can reapply with in 28 days of refusal with the same sponsorship documents , but you will have to satisfy the ECO;
2. You will have to get new letter from your employer with the specific dates of visiting abroad. You may ad up 3/4 days
3. Your bank transaction in November does not consistent with the previous deposit history. So you should explain satisfactorily that why the transaction history is different with the past.
4. The ECO is not satisfied with the origin of the funds specifically shown in  NOV.
5. If you think that you can satisfy the ECO on the above matters you should reapply , otherwise wait till your circumstances are changed

Comment: While this answer is longer than your other answers, it also lacks all links and quotes, all proof that this is more than just your imagination.